# How to make processes not die after its parent dies?

Tags: process, c, process-management, fork

I've been messing with forkbombs and noticed that if I just fork() processes repeatedly, killing the initial process will bring down the whole tree. This is not the case for forkbombs written in BASH using its backgrounding operator &, so I know there's a way around this. How do I achieve the same result in C?

I've been using forkbomb examples from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Example_fork_bombs

Comment: You're probably looking for `setpgid`. Haven't tested, or I'd make this an answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing this in C, you need to do a `setsid(2)` in your code, along with some `fork()` and `exit()` calls.  `setsid()` has this effect:

> ... creates a new session if the calling process is not a process
>   group leader.  The calling process is the leader of  the  new 
>   session, the  process group leader of the new process group, and has
>   no controlling tty.

That's from the man page. Basically, if a process that's a process group leader gets certain signals, every process ID in that process group gets the signal.  You can see the mechanism for this in the `kill(2)` man page. If the PID you call `kill()` on is negative, the signal gets sent to every process in the process group.

You also need to `fork()` and `exit()` in the right places. Basically look at [instructions on how to become a daemon process](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/daemons/become_daemon.c.html). The parts you need to do:

```
switch (fork()) {
case -1: return -1;
case 0:  break;
default: _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

setsid();

switch (fork()) {
case -1: return -1;
case 0:  break;
default: _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Read about becoming a daemon process for more of the rationale behind this code.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to background a process and then keep it up. If the command was started and then backgrounded with `&` you can use this command to disconnect it from your terminal.

```
$ disown -a
```

If you want to insulate the process from the hang up signal (HUP) and also disconnect it from the terminal (tty) you can use this commands as well:

```
$ nohup <cmd>
```

Any console output will be written to a file, `nohup.out`.

So I would suggest that you could do something clever after the process has been backgrounded with the `disown -a` command, would be one idea.

For other ideas take a look at my answer to this U&L question, titled: [Where is the fork() on the fork bomb :(){ :|: & };:?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89003/where-is-the-fork-on-the-fork-bomb).

#### C

I'd take a look at this thread from SO, titled: [C: Exec/fork > Defunct processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718272/c-exec-fork-defunct-processes), specifically this answer by [@Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718997/33204).

Comment: ... except OP asked how to achieve the same result in C.

Comment: @derobert - yeah I realized that, but this isn't a programming site so I showed him the U&L methods..

Comment: OP is asking about the "UNIX C API and System Interfaces", which is part of the site, at least according to the Help Center.

Comment: @derobert - true, I'm looking up the C API eqiv. now. Interestingly all the answers are on SO 8-). Even more interesting the answer I'm reading is by Gilles.

Comment: @derobert - bruce beat me to it.