# How to terminate a background process in Linux when the pid is unknown?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, background-process

I have a job dispatcher bash shell script containing below codes:

```
for (( i=0; i<$toBeDoneNum; i=i+1 ))
do
    while true
    do
            processNum=`ps aux | grep Checking | wc -l`
            if [ $processNum -lt $maxProcessNum ]; then
                break
            fi
            echo "Too many processes: Max process is $maxProcessNum."
            sleep $sleepSec
    done
    java -classpath ".:./conf:./lib/*" odx.comm.cwv.main.Checking $i
done
```

I run the script like this to be in the background:

```
./dispatcher.sh &
```

I want to terminate this dispatcher process with `kill -9`. But I didn't record the pid of the dispatcher process at the first time. I used jobs, `jobs -l`, `jobs -r` and `jobs -s`. Nothing showed. Even this `fg` cannot bring the process to foreground.

```
fg
bash: fg: current: no such job
```

But I think this dispatcher process is still running because it still continues to assign java program to run (already used top and `ps -ef` to check). How should I terminate this job dispatcher bash shell script process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just kill the script by name using the `pkill` command.

```
$ pkill -9 dispatcher.sh
```

*excerpt from [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)*

```
pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other 
               attributes

OPTIONS
       -signal
       --signal signal
              Defines the signal to send to each matched process.  Either 
              the numeric or the symbolic signal name can be used.  (pkill 
              only.)
```

See the [man page for `pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) for more info.

#### Finding processes

If you find that you no longer know a process's process ID (PID) you can find it a couple of ways.

#### pgrep

You can use `pgrep` to find a process by name.

```
$ pgrep dispatcher.sh
12345
```

You can then perform a `kill -8 12345`.

#### ps

Most people learned to find PID's using `ps`. You can look for your process in the output like this.

```
$ ps -eaf | grep [d]ispatcher.sh
saml      2735     1  0 Jan11 ?        00:02:50 dispatcher.sh
```

The PID is the 2nd column in the output (typically). The above trick where I wrap the first letter of the process I'm looking for eliminates the `grep` from showing up in the results. Try it without the square brackets to see what I mean.

Comment: The thing I cannot realize is that even jobs, pgrep and ps cannot find the dispatcher process. But new jobs are still being assigned.  Really strange.

Comment: Looks like you made yourself a little form bomb type of script. Look for `while` and `for` processes.

Comment: What do you mean by form bomb? Does my syntax go wrong?

Comment: Sorry that should've said fork bomb. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89003/where-is-the-fork-on-the-fork-bomb

Comment: @MarcusThornton Given the code you've posted, I can't think of anything to add to slm's answer. If you need more help, post the whole script. Also post `ps l` lines for some of these Java processes, look at the PPID line and see what their parent is.

Comment: Personally, I think we should educate other users, that e.g. `-9` is equivalent to `-KILL` and should be preferred as it is self-explanatory. Further, I think you should not recommend `SIGKILL` as the first aid. Rather than that I would post in this order: `pkill -HUP`, `pkill -TERM`, `pkill -KILL` in a non-specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the Java processes spawned by the dispatcher in the output of the ps, try to check the PPID of these processes. Check if it is a bash process, and if so, try killing it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your full script it seems what you are trying to do is simply to have a given number of jobs running in parallel. Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
# -q to avoid lib/* expanding
seq 0 $toBeDoneNum |
  parallel -j $maxProcessNum -q java -classpath ".:./conf:./lib/*" odx.comm.cwv.main.Checking
```