# :(){:|:&};: How does this BASH fork bomb work in detail?

Tags: scripting, function, fork

I have a very fragmentary understanding of shells, subshells, functions, background processes and therefore I am insecure in understanding how this fork bomb works in detail,

However I tell you how what I know:

- :() Here the colon is simply an unusually looking function name
- {...} Here is described what the function is doing
- {:()} Here the function calls the next iteration of itself
- {:()&} Here the function calls itself and puts the next iteration of itself into the background of the shell
- ...;: The last colon is the starting point of the function's actual execution, what is before is just its definition

So, my basic understanding is, it is a recursive function, which works like a spawning machine, spawning copies of itself until the point the system can not proliferate social wellfare anymore.

But, I do not really understand in a visually way what is happening step by step.

For instance

- :()|:()&  Why are both function callings combined through a pipe symbol?
- Is the fork bomb spawning in a linear fashion, a constant number of processes per time unit or is it more abombically exponential like the two function calls suggest.

Could some one provide additionally a visual step by step comic strip of the spawning process, no matter how sloppy?

Comment: While it is a pipe symbol/character it isnt a pipe it is an or in this case IIRC

Comment: Definitely it is, but I wanted to risk a double explanation because I hoped to get a visual answer , a diagram, instead of an answer which leaves some obscurity unexplained, at least to the people with less knowledge.

Comment: @ivanivan no, it is a pipe. That’s how the bomb scales: both sides of the pipe start in parallel...

Comment: does it have a special name, when one function is piped into another or is there no difference when comparing an ordinary command pipes into another command?

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%3A%28%29%7B+%3A+%7C+%3A%26+%7D%3B+%3A

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a visual explanation; sorry it’s not a comic, but it should illustrate:

- step 1: run the function

  ```
  :
  ```
- step 2: the function runs two copies of itself, using a pipe to start both in parallel (the backgrounding operator doesn’t really seem to matter here, as described in the answer to [How does a fork bomb work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88946/86440))

  ```
  (:|:)
  ```

  (I’m using parentheses here just for clarity)
- step 3: repeat the process for each `:`

  ```
  ((:|:)|(:|:))
  ```
- and so it goes on

  ```
  (((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))
  ```

  and on, replacing each `:` with `(:|:)` at every step

  ```
  ((((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))|(((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:))))

  (((((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))|(((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:))))|((((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))|(((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))))

  ((((((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))|(((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:))))|((((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))|(((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))))|(((((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))|(((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:))))|((((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:)))|(((:|:)|(:|:))|((:|:)|(:|:))))))
  ```

etc. until the system runs out of resources (by which time it will have become very unresponsive indeed).