# Why is "&" necessary to make a Unix fork bomb work?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, fork

Consider the canonical example of a Unix fork bomb:

**DANGER**: running the following command, might crash your system.

```
:(){ :|: & };:
```

I wonder why `&` (background) is needed in order to use up all of the system's resources - after all the function `:` is recursive? Also, I have attempted to execute `:` without `&`, but in this case Bash doesn't accept the syntax, why?

Comment: As to why it didn't accept the syntax: https://askubuntu.com/a/521943

Comment: @muru - so the only purpose of `&` is to make the fork bomb run faster? At least that's what I understand from your answer :)

Comment: Not my answer. However, seems like it. There's at least [one other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88947/70524), which says it isn't necessary: "I note that at least on my Arch VM, the need to background the process is not a requirement to have the same end result, to consume all available process space and render the host b0rked."